# KEDA not scheduling multiple pods on node

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, keda

I'm trying to implement a KEDA deployment. The deployment has to schedule pods on a node when messages in the queue appear. Now for some reason when I insert multiple messages in my queue there's only one pod being scheduled. I would like multiple pods being scheduled for the work to be done faster. Is there something I'm missing?

Below is my deployment yml.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: maps-service
  namespace: maps-service
  labels:
    app: maps-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: maps-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: maps-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: maps-service
          image: xxxxxx:latest
          env:
            - name: AzureFunctionsJobHost__functions__0
              value: maps-service
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: maps-service
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 512Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 0.5
              memory: 256Mi
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 240
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 80
              scheme: HTTP
          startupProbe:
            failureThreshold: 3
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 240
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 80
              scheme: HTTP
---
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: maps-service
  namespace: maps-service
  labels: {}
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: maps-service
  pollingInterval: 10
  cooldownPeriod: 10
  minReplicaCount: 0
  maxReplicaCount: 30
  triggers:
    - type: azure-queue
      metadata:
        direction: in
        queueName: maps-requests
        connectionFromEnv: storage-account-connection-string
---
```